# running chart.js locally on webpage not displaying charts

Tags: chart.js

I want to be able to use chart,js offline and run it locally on a webpage.

so the original way to run it which works is to source the following:

```
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js'></script>
```

when i download the github files

```
https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/download/v4.2.0/chart.js-4.2.0.tgz
```

I upack the content in a folder on the same level as my htm page
OR
I install chart,js thorugh npm and copy/paste the files in a folder on the same level as my htm page

and then i source the chart.js file like this

```
<script src='chart/dist/chart.js'></script>
```

It doesn't work.....
my graphs wont load.

I even tried copying the content of file

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js
```

and pasting it in a chart.js file, but still it doesn't show my graphs, while if i would source it form the the site above it shows my graphs perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same error, I downloaded the package and unpacked it into /scripts/chartjs/ under www-root.

That folder has now this content:

```
02/13/2023  08:59 PM    <DIR>          .
02/13/2023  08:59 PM    <DIR>          ..
02/13/2023  08:59 PM    <DIR>          auto
02/13/2023  08:59 PM    <DIR>          dist
02/13/2023  08:59 PM    <DIR>          helpers
10/26/1985  02:15 AM             1,093 LICENSE.md
10/26/1985  02:15 AM             4,359 package.json
10/26/1985  02:15 AM             2,640 README.md
               3 File(s)          8,092 bytes
               5 Dir(s)  711,093,805,056 bytes free
```

I call the package in my html header with

```
<script src="/scripts/chartjs/dist/chart.umd.js"></script>
```

It works. Unfortunately the documentation is not very clear.